# Conditional Where Clause (based on rank)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display a taxonomic list of state birds that looks something like this:

Order Falconiformes
Family Falconidae
peregrine falcon (*Falco Perergrinus*) | Idaho
Order Passeriformes
Family Turdidae
robin (*Turdus migratorius*) | Connecticut, Michigan, Wisconsin

I can't figure out how to make a single query that does what I want, so I'm trying to figure out a workaround.

This is my basic query:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT PLAN.Latin Latin2, PLAN.Common, PLAN.Group1, PLAN.Rank, PLAN.Family, PLAN.Order1, GS.Symbol, GS.Latin, GROUP_CONCAT(GG.Name ORDER BY GG.Name ASC SEPARATOR ', ') as Names, GG.IDParent
FROM gs_planimals PLAN
LEFT JOIN gs GS ON GS.Latin = PLAN.Latin
LEFT JOIN gw_geog GG ON GG.IDArea = GS.IDArea
WHERE PLAN.Group1 = :RefCat AND Rank != '55'
GROUP BY PLAN.Common
ORDER BY PLAN.N, GG.Name");
$stm->execute(array(
'RefCat'=>$RefCat,
));
```

I can then use this to style the rows...

```
switch($Rank)
{
 case 35:
 $SymRow = '<tr class="Red Center"><td colspan="2" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;"> <em>Order</em> <b>'.$Order.'</b> ('.$Common.')</td></tr>';
 break;
 case 45:
 $SymRow = '<tr class="Blue"><td colspan="2">&gt; <em>Family</em> <b>'.$Family.'</b>   ('.$Common.')</td></tr>';
 break;
 case 65:
 $SymRow = '
 <tr>
 <td class="Symbol">&gt;&gt; <a href="'.$GZ_URL.'/life/'.$LatinL.'" title="'.$Symbol.' ('.$Latin2.')">'.$row['Common'].'</a> (<em>'.$Latin2.'</em>)</td>
 <td class="Place"><a href="/world/'.$PlaceL.'" title="'.$Place.'">'.$PlaceGroup.'</a>  </td>
 </tr>
';
 break;
 default:
 $SymRow = '';
 break;
}
```

...where a rank of 35 = an order, 45 = a family and 65 = a species. This works, but it displays EVERYTHING related to birds in the table gs_planimals. I want to display only U.S. state birds and their grandparents (families) and great grandparents (orders).

If I modify the WHERE clause to indicate a geographic parent, like this...

```
WHERE PLAN.Group1 = 'bird' AND Rank != '55' **AND GG.IDParent = 'usa'**
```

Then it works for species (rank 65). However, no families or orders display at all, presumably because families and orders aren't linked to the tables gs or gw_geog.

So I'd like to know if there's a way to write a conditional WHERE CLAUSE, something like this...

```
WHERE PLAN.Group1 = 'bird' AND Rank != '55' [AND **- if Rank = 65 -** GG.IDParent = 'usa']
```

If I can do this, then the table should still display every order and family in the table, but I can put together some PHP switches that manually delete orders and families I don't want to display.

Anyway, does anyone now how to modify a where clause like that? If not, can you suggest another workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relocate the predicate

```
GG.IDParent = 'usa'
```

from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`

In the WHERE clause, that predicate negates the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN. Any rows that don't have a "matching" row from `GG`, all of the `GG.` columns will be NULL, and those rows won't satisfy that predicate in the `WHERE` clause.

```
LEFT JOIN gw_geog GG ON GG.IDArea = GS.IDArea AND GG.IDParent = 'usa'
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Interesting. It isn't working at the moment; it's still displaying ALL the bird taxons in table gs_planimals. I thought the problem might be related to the GROUP clause, but I haven't had any luck there. If I delete GROUP BY PLAN.Common entirely, nothing displays at all. Anyway, I think you gave me the right answer, but I just need to play with my query a little more to figure out what's going on. Thx!

Comment: The answer I gave explains how to return rows that don't have matching rows from GG. With that predicate in the WHERE clause, you'll get ONLY rows that have a matching GG row. I'm not understanding the requirements for the set of rows you want to return.

Comment: If I want to display a list of U.S. state birds, then I only want to display rows associated with 1) birds and 2) U.S. states. That's easy to do on the species level (Rank = 65), because species are listed in the table GS, with each row linked with the table gw_geog. However, families and orders are only listed in planimals, and I don't know how to associate them with the other tables. However, I just came up with a workaround...

Comment: Using your code, it still displays ALL birds...but geographic names are displayed only for U.S. state birds. So I just created a PHP switch that displays only species rows (Rank 65) that have geographic values. Now I just have to figure out a way to not display all the "orphaned" orders and families. ;)